# Use GeoNames Java API to retrieve coordinates given Wikipedia article title

Tags: wikipedia, geonames

Say I have the title of a Wikipedia article, e.g. Philadelphia, and I want the coordinates of that place. I don't want to get this from Wikipedia because it looks like I'd have to retrieve the whole article. And I don't want to just loosely query GeoNames for places "like philadelphia" because that will have lots of results, and I know I want the specific Wikipedia article [[Philadelphia]]'s coordinates.

It seems like the GeoNames API allows you to do this with the class [WikipediaArticle](http://www.geonames.org/source-code/javadoc/org/geonames/WikipediaArticle.html) and its methods like setTitle() and getLatitude(). But I've been fiddling around with that class and [WebService](http://www.geonames.org/source-code/javadoc/org/geonames/WebService.html) and haven't been able to retrieve the coordinates that way. I won't bore you with all the combinations I've tried, but I can't find an example of how to do it. Something like:

```
WebService.setUserName("whateveritis");
List<WikipediaArticle> wikiResults = WebService.wikipediaSearchForTitle(
                            "Philadelphia","en");
for (WikipediaArticle r : wikiResults) {
    System.out.println(r.getLatitude());
}
```

That gives a lot of errors, that I can share, but make me think I'm just using it wrong. Or maybe:

```
WikipediaArticle myPlace = new WikipediaArticle();
myPlace.setTitle("Philadelphia");
Double lat = myPlace.getLatitude();
```

This returns 0.0. Is anyone familiar with API and can tell me where I'm going wrong? I do think it's meant to do stuff like this because the web version does it: http://api.geonames.org/wikipediaSearch?title=Philadelphia&maxRows=1&username=demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way, using WebService.wikipediaSearchForTitle, is the way to do this, but you have to have jdom set up properly in the classpath--which I thought I had, but didn't. However, note that the function returns any article with "Philadelphia" in the title, not just exactly Phildelphia. So the function, even when working, didn't do quite what I needed.